# Tooltip for intersecting items in a listbox

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, wpf-controls, tooltip

Similar to the blog post here, http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaelr/archive/2010/08/11/zoomableapplication2-a-million-items.aspx

I have lot of curves in my zoomable-canvas. The curves are intersecting and placed densely. I have added tooltips to the shapes.

Say I have 3 intersecting curves A, B, C (not the same geometrically), which are within a bounding box. Now the tooltips are displayed only for the shape that is on top of all.

All the curves are visible, but somehow there is a invisible region that bounds each curve and mouseover event is triggered only for the shape on the top and tooltip is displayed for it.

How do I make tooltip displayed for all the shapes?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to say but WPF does not have this built in (well as far as I know). You will have to create your own ToolTipService.

Basically when your mouse moves you will have to do a HitTest on all UIElements you are interested in. Then when their is a hit you will have to show your custom ToolTip control.

Here is something to get you stated:

#### Code Behind

```
private void WindowMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    EllipseGeometry hitArea = new EllipseGeometry(e.GetPosition(this), 5, 5);
    VisualTreeHelper.HitTest(MainGrid, null, new HitTestResultCallback(ToolTipCallback), new GeometryHitTestParameters(hitArea));//MainGrid would be your ListBox
}

private HitTestResultBehavior ToolTipCallback(HitTestResult hitTestResult)
{
    GeometryHitTestResult geometryHitTestResult = ((GeometryHitTestResult)hitTestResult);

    if (geometryHitTestResult.VisualHit.GetType() == typeof(Rectangle))
    {
        Path potentialToolTip = (Path)geometryHitTestResult.VisualHit;

        if (potentialToolTip.Tag.ToString().Contains("CustomToolTip"))
        {
            //Show Custom ToolTip
            return HitTestResultBehavior.Stop;
        }
    }
    return HitTestResultBehavior.Stop;
}
```